# notepad++ regex remove tags and content

Tags: regex, notepad++

`<description><![CDATA[<span style="font-weight: bold;">..text content...</span></description>`

i want to remove all the description data

output: `<description></description>`

how can i remove

Comment: input:  <description><![CDATA[<span style="font-weight: bold;">..text content...</span></description>
output: <description></description>

Answer (score -1):

Do a find and replace:

Find what: `(<description>)(.+?)(<\/description>)`

Replace with: `\1\3`

Search mode: Regular expression